# Tell me please about the 301 redirect Nginx if there is a GET parameter

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Tell me please.
There is a link like: `mysite.com/blablabla/efefefe.html/? Param_a = 1`
How to make 301 redirects to `mysite.com / blablabla / efefefe.html /`
Thanks a lot

Comment: This needs to be in _English_

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I try this
  if ($arg_admin_view = 1) {
      rewrite (.*)$ $uri permanent;
    }
don't work(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a question mark after $uri - `$uri?`. Nginx will remove all get parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very inconsiderate